# Bypassing <, > XSS filter

Tags: xss, html, reflected-xss

`<img class="avatar" src="MY INPUT SPACE">`

I am trying to bypass an XSS filter but it is not working since given `<`, `>` are filtered. I feel like it I could break it since only these two characters are filtered but I just couldn't find a way to do it, any suggestion on this?

Comment: If just those are filtered, write out the html tag as you normally would, and apply the injection half afterwards. Example: `<img class="avatar" src="imghere.jpg" onload="javascript:alert('lol');"/>`. So, input `imghere.jpg" onload="javascript:alert('lol');`?

Comment: It looks like I am getting there, however the there is no alert showing.
I am getting:<img class="image" src="http://www.image.com/1" onload="javascript:alert('lol')></p></figure><div class=" content"="">

Comment: @Mark Buffalo After a few attempts, I am able to make the site to store a image of:
<img class="avatar-image" src="https://petco.scene7.com/is/image/PETCO/849430-center-3?$ProductDetail-large$&quot;><script>alert(1)</script>">
but the script is never excuted

Comment: Why are you adding a semi-colon after the `src` attribute?

Comment: What about loading an external javascript file using https://www.myevilsite.org/injections.js or something similar. This assuming you have "real" control over src=

Answer (score 3):

The general advice (to inject an event handler in the image tag) from @MarkBuffalo in the comment is correct, but `onload` isn't a great choice of event handler for images. The better option is usually `onerror`, which is very easy to reliably trigger; just set the source to be something you know won't exist (or at least won't be an image), like `src="qq" onerror="alert('XSS!')"`.

The specific exception I like is SVG tags, where `<svg onload="…" />` is a nice short string (as short as `<script>…</script>`, and usable in places that try stupid tricks like filtering `<script>`).

Comment: Just wondering, but why isn't `onload` a good choice for images? It works for me pretty much every time. However, stuff like buttons, or other elements, sure.

Comment: You could also add some more to the tag, so it isn't that obvious, that the image is hijacked: add ` style="display:none"` to hide it or set another background-image so it looks normal afterwards