# Bypass a simple XSS filter that only looks at <

Tags: web-application, xss, javascript, html, jquery

Say, I have a page where the input from the user is taken and is passed through a simple client-side XSS filter. That filter only replaces `<` characters with ''.

```
in = in.replace(/[<]/g, '');
```

The input is then passed on to JQuery's `html()` method in order to embed the user input inside a `<div>` tag.

How can we bypass this simple XSS filter?

Comment: Check these: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: If your filters are only on client side then they can be bypassed using proxy interceptor like Burp Suite.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bypassing <, > XSS filter](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/183755/bypassing-xss-filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSS in a simple HTML context without `<` is [not possible](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=xss%20without%20<%20site%3Asecurity.stackexchange.com). It would be possible in a HTML attribute context, JavaScript context, etc; but in a simple `<div>` tag, we need `<`.

I see no way to bypass the regex; It will always correctly remove all `<` characters from the string.

The only hope left is that the jQuery function `.html` might insecurely handle the input (eg decode values), which would allow us to bypass the filter. But there are no known vulnerabilities in `.html` that I am aware of.

Given the above, I would say that there is no vulnerability here.